# Compare all object elements of two different arrays

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-redux

sorry for my English at the start.
I have a problem with filtering a list of products posted in JSON. The code is written in react native with the use of react redux.

The object of each product looks like this:

```
ProductTest {
 "barcode": "barcode",
 "brand": "brand",
 "category": "category",
 "description": "description",
 "details": "details",
 "filters": Object {
   "cienkie": false,
   "farbowane": false,
   "krecone_i_puszczace": false,
   "normalne": false,
   "oslabione": false,
   "przetluszczajace": false,
   "suche_i_zniszczone": false,
   "wszystkie": true,
 },
 "id": "0",
 "image": "image",
 "ingredients": "ingredients",
 "name": "name",
},
```

And the "appliedFilters" list looks like this:

```
Object {
 "cienkie": false,
 "farbowane": false,
 "krecone_i_puszczace": false,
 "normalne": false,
 "oslabione": false,
 "przetluszczajace": false,
 "suche_i_zniszczone": false,
 "wszystkie": false,
}
```

I don't know how to make the "appliedFilters" list to be compared with the "filters" for each product, and to return the matching products from the list.
If you have any ideas I would be greatful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54383583/18391173 refer this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **array filter** method :

```
let keys = Object.keys(appliedFilters); 
let filteredList = productList.filter(product => {
  let matching = true;
  keys.forEach(key => {
   if(product.hasOwnProperty(key)){
     if(!(product.filters[key] === appliedFilters[key])) matching = false;
   }
  }
  if(matching) return product;
})
```

If you are sure that the attributes order of the filter and the product objects will not change, you can simplify like this :

```
let filteredList = productList.filter(product => JSON.stringify(product.filters) === JSON.stringify(appliedFilters))
```

Comment: ok. there is only one filter correctly applied to the list, and I need that in a situation when appliedfilters has several values with true, all matching products will show up.

For example: 
`appliedfilters: {
Object {
 "cienkie": true,
 "farbowane": true,
}
}
PRODUCTS: {
ProductTest1 {
 "filters": Object {
   "cienkie": true,
   "farbowane": false,
 }
}
ProductTest2 {
 "filters": Object {
   "cienkie": false,
   "farbowane": true,
 }
}
}
return Array [ProductTest1; ProductTest2];`

Comment: So, you want the products that match at least one filter !  Change this line `let matching = true;` to `let matching = false;` and this one `if(!(product.filters[key] === appliedFilters[key])) matching = false;` to `if(product.filters[key] === appliedFilters[key]) matching = true;`

Comment: This way returns nothing. 
**First one:**
`let matching = true;
        keys.forEach((key) => {
          if (product.filters.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (!(product.filters[key] === appliedFilters[key]))
              matching = false;
          }
        });`
Returns products that match only one filter. if more than one filter is selected returns empty array.

Comment: **Second one:**
`let matching = false;
        keys.forEach((key) => {
          if (product.filters.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if ((product.filters[key] === appliedFilters[key]))
              matching = true;
          }
        });`
Returns the entire list of products, no matter which filter I choose. When more than one product is selected, the entire list of products is also returned.